# Copying HTML Code From Another IDE Is Displaying A Different Output

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-deployment

I want to display a button in my project and I have created a `button.css` file that stores all the CSS for creating the button. Initially, I used the whole code from a different source but have managed to copy and paste the css code into the `button.css` file except the HTML code. I am having issues with the html code and don't know where to paste it in my `index.html` file. I tried working with it but it would produce a totally different output with just a simple and plain box that says "Check Out My Blogs!"

The HTML Code I want To Paste In My index.html file:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/button.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

 <div id="container">
  <button class="learn-more">
    <span class="circle" aria-hidden="true">
      <span class="icon arrow"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="button-text">Check Out My Blogs!</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

My Main index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <title >Hussain Omer</title>
    <meta content="" name="descriptison">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i"
     rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-180664536-1">
    </script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-180664536-1');

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- ======= Mobile nav toggle button ======= -->

    <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
    <header id="header" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

        <nav class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#hero"><i class="bx bx-home"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="bx bx-user"></i> <span>About Me</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume"><i class="bx bx-file-blank"></i> <span>Resume</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio"><i class="bx bx-book-content"></i> <span>Projects</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><i class="bx bx-server"></i> <span>Blogs</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><i class="bx bx-server"></i> <span>Skills</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="bx bx-envelope"></i> <span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->

  </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
      <h1>Hussain Omer</h1>
      <p>I'm a <span class="typed" data-typed-items="Coder, Leader, Team-Player, Blog Writer, Adventurer"></span></p>
      <div class="social-links">
        <!--<a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>-->
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kaustubh-prabhakar/" class="linkedin"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://github.com/SantaKaus" class="github"><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com/h.s.z_11/" class="instagram"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section><!-- End Hero -->

  <main id="main">

    <!-- ======= About Section ======= -->
    <section id="about" class="about portfolio services">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>My Story</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Lahore, Pakistan (2003-2010)</h4>
                <p>I was born in Lahore, the second largest city of Pakistan. This is where I did most of my education and developed many memories. I enjoyed the very bit of the city; from the diverse culture and to the beautiful greenary. I haven't visited Pakistan in over 5 years, and I hope to go back some day &#128512;
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Helsinki, Finland (2007-2010)</h4>
                <p>From a very unique and enjoyable Finnish school syst
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Helsinki, Finland (2007-2010)</h4>
                <p>From a very unique and enjoyable Finnish school syst

       </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
<div class="section-title">
          <h2>About ME</h2>
           <p>I am a 17 year old with a enthusiastic drive to working with technology, and using my prowess in Computers to make a positive impact on this world. </p>
           </div>
  <img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1?ui=2&ik=79098a413c&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-f:1687893372595235455&th=176c9a145c466a7f&view=att&disp=safe&realattid=176c9a0f10e523984941" align="left" width="370" height="500">

<!-- <div style="display:inline-block;"> to put text under something or start new --> 
  <div class="aligned">
    <div class="p">
           <p>Motivated by my love for numbers, I started to explore the many ways I can use my Mathematical knowledge and implement it into different areas. I was introduced to Computer Science in my junior years of high school, and I came to know that I was genuinely passionated about learning it. It offers a holistic approach to solve problems which I admire, and since then, I have transformed my interest into a personal hobby!</p>
           <p>I would always like to challenge myself and learn new programming langauges to increase the size of my toolbox. I was inspired by one of my friends to take my programming skills and put it into a good use; thus, I was introduced to competitive programming and large coding events such as hackathons!</p>
           <p>The intellectual challenges, creativity, and logic programming offers has always further strengthened the inevitable bond between us.</p>
           <p>Challenging myself allows me to not only grow outside my comfort zone, but gives a new perspective towards life, and how there is no limitations/boundaries that halt you from growing! It is everlasting. Once you develop the growth mindset, your journey just never comes to a complete stop! You keep on growing outside your comfort zone, and being able to easily push through any obstacles.</p>
          <blockquote>
          Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
          <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
           </blockquote>
        </div>
    </section><!-- End About Section -->
    <!-- ======= Facts Section ======= -->
    <section id="facts" class="facts">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>What I am upto &#128515;</h2>
        </div>
      
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h4 class="title">7CUPS.com</h4>
            <p class="description">I am currently on the pursuit to make a positive impact on the world. To do this, I started volunteering with 7Cups as a trained listener to support people having emotional distress by interacting with them and resolving any concerns they might have. Especially in these unprecendented times (a.k.a when COVID hit), it is important to guide and support the ones that require additional assistance</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <h4 class="title">School Clubs</h4>
            <p class="description">Being part of school clubs is personally my favourite thing:) Interacting with people, coming up with ideas and implementing it with various activities is a fun on its own! I am currently an active member of over 5 clubs and hold a Vice-President position at my school's STEM Club. I am also the Technical Team Member for our school's Student Tech Hub</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 icon-box" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            <h4 class="title">Blog Writing</h4>
            <p class="description">This is my new favourite thing to do when I am bored:) You may wonder what kind of blogs I write and specifically about what genre I write about. The answer is everything! I write about what is on my mind, and what I learn from my experiences. Basically self-reflections. I also tend to give general advices to people through my blogs!</p>
    
    

          </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section><!-- End Facts Section -->

    
</body>

</html>
```

**The html code may look very long but I want the button to be displayed after "This is my new favourite thing to do when I am bored........" which is near the very bottom**

**So where should the HTML code go for it to display the button right after the line I said above? I tried putting the code after the line but it wouldnt work for some reason. Could you guys please help?**

Here is the Button.css file which has the css for my button:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta:700");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #f3f8fa;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
}
button.learn-more {
  width: 12rem;
  height: auto;
}
button.learn-more .circle {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: #282936;
  border-radius: 1.625rem;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  left: 0.625rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 0.125rem;
  background: none;
}
button.learn-more .circle .icon.arrow::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -0.25rem;
  right: 0.0625rem;
  width: 0.625rem;
  height: 0.625rem;
  border-top: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  border-right: 0.125rem solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
button.learn-more .button-text {
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.076, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 1.85rem;
  color: #282936;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
button:hover .circle {
  width: 125%;
}
button:hover .circle .icon.arrow {
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(1rem, 0);
}
button:hover .button-text {
  color: #fff;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0.625rem;
    grid-template-areas: ". main main ." ". main main .";
  }

  #yes {
    grid-area: main;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Errors in console? Are all your dependencies found?

Comment: There are no errors, but I am getting different output and not the output I want

Comment: So all your "assets" are found?

Comment: Yes my assets are found

Comment: Then how do you explain your (css) styling issue?

Comment: My css for the button is saved in button.css file and there is no issue with that. I do not know where to put the HTML code for the button in my main index.html file for it to output the button after the line I stated. If I put the HTML code after the line I stated, it does not work

Comment: Where is your `button.css` code since your theory thats the problem?

Comment: Button.css is not a problem! The problem is where should I put the HTML code in my index.html file for it to output the button after the line I stated

Comment: Ok. Asking for help but you already know where the problem is without errors? How?

Comment: I just would like to know where I can put my HTML code in my index.html file for it to output the button. Thats all.

Comment: Your css will be global since its included in the `head` tag. Unless you show `button.css` then whatever CSS syntax errors there will remain the mystery you seem to prefer. ... Again I wonder why ask for help then be uncooperative on that help?

Comment: Okay, I will also add button.css in the post above

Comment: Ok. Just paste the code between your head tags on the former to the latter file Between the head tags. See what happens

Comment: paste what code and where sorry?

Comment: Between `<head></head>`. You show two html files right? One has the includes you want, one doesn't. Have you tried just simply prepending the former to the latter?

Comment: Paste my html code between the head tags in the index.html file, right? I already tried that and it doesnt work. Even if it did work, I want the button to output after the line I stated above

Comment: I see you prefer difficulty or maybe just ambuiguity. You are supposed to mention what you already tried. The code in your question is actually (ideally) supposed to be exactly what you tried. SO isn't a guessing game. The code you show in your "2nd" html file in fact, does not do what  I suggested.

Comment: I am going to share with you a link of the platform where I have the button and its output. And also the link of my main project where I want to copy and paste the button code. I will explain more later once you are on the platform, just click these two links

Comment: I'm actually done helping you. I suggest closing this question and opening another one. This comment thread got us no where fast.